# (VBA) Extract and copy and paste column values for specified date range for corresponding row values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been stuck on this for a while now. What I need is the title - what I have is:

Sheet 1:
1 billion mostly unnecessary columns.

```
Column D: Values I need         Column F:         Column M:
Revenue                         Names             Date

12                              John              1/24/2016  2:40:02 AM
15                              Sarah             3/2/2016   4:35:17 PM
14                              Sarah             7/17/2016  1:50:10 PM
20                              Matt              8/20/2012  4:16:12 AM
10                              John              11/19/2015 5:04:05 AM
etc.                            etc.
```

**Current** Sheet 2: **Pivot Table***

```
Row Label:                  
Sarah     
Matt
John
etc.
```

**Desired** Sheet 2 **Pivot Table+***

```
Row Label:             Column __:  
                       Revenue

Sarah                  29
Matt                   0 *(note: see below, but = 0 because Matts value corresponded to date 2012)
John                   22
etc.
```

The important thing about Sheet 2 is that I would like to tell VBA to find the nearest emptiest column within the sheet, and input the values from Column D from S1 (and sum for duplicates) but only sum and extract values that range from today's date to 11 months prior. Currently I made a module to automatically create a pivot table for the next sheet, but I have wanted to add the above for a while, just stuck.

I'm also assuming I won't have to specify sum if I tell VBA to extract data for corresponding row label names? And I was thinking about putting a Begin Date and End Date cells on Sheet 2 to refer to, or using the TODAY() function somehow for the date, but not sure how to specify to extract and sum values for the date range from today to 11 months prior.

Edit: *Please note this is a watered down version of my current situation, everything is bigger so to avoid confusion, pivots are necessary, but I choose to dilute it for the sake of this issue.

Comment: why use pivot table? is it because you want to remove duplicate names?

Comment: You might find it is quicker to place a pivot table over all your raw data and then filter the pivot results.  Not sure where VBA would add value here?  Is it to improve performance?  How does your current VBA work?  Does it copy a subset of the data into a new tab and then pivot that?

Comment: @destination-data - yes to the second question. I need the pivot table for separate reasons as it grabs a subset of the source file which has too much data, but the next emptiest column I would want VBA to work with is a part of the solution. For example, parallel to 2+3 = 5, this column I would want VBA to generate would be the 3. I would filter the pivot, but when I try to add in that "column D" from the source file, Excel tells me it's too large to pivot.

Comment: The basic approach is to write a loop that reads the source data from top to bottom.  It should read one row at a time.  Each required row should be copied to a destination (normally another worksheet).  Not sure what your skill level is?  Can you write the loop?  If not you should probably start there.  Breaking this into the individual steps, and mastering each, will help you learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need a pivot table?

If you dont, just create a new sheet with all the names, set a cell for the starting date you want to consider and do =sumifs

For example

On Sheet2 B1 you put 1/24/2016.
Then on A2 you insert the name (Sarah, for example)
On B2 you put the formula

```
=Sumifs(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!F:F,A2,Sheet1!M:M,">"&B$1)
```

After that just make a list of name and drag the formula beside every name.

*My excel is in portuguese so maybe the formula needs some other ajustments to work.

Comment: Sadly, I do need a pivot table for separate reasons - much more complicated than what I put up there - but I only put the necessary info. in my question to avoid further convoluted-ness. As for the formula above, will that be able to only sum for values contained in the past 11 months?

Comment: Exactly. The ">"$B$1 inside the sumifs says that the condition for sum is if its higher than the date on that cell. If you change the B1 cell value for today's date, it will only sum if the date is after today

Comment: So I tried that and then I also tried a variation of that with, `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!K:K,A2,Sheet1!M:M,">="&TODAY()-11,Sheet1!M:M,"<="&TODAY())`- but both ways give me back 0

Comment: =Sumifs("Column where the value you want to sum are","First criteria column","First criteria","second criteria column","second criteria"

Comment: Remember it will only sum if it matches ALL criteria.

Comment: Yep, followed that format. I'm thinking there's something up with the date (maybe the way it's formatted?), because the first criteria by itself with a simple sumif function works fine, but I can't say the same for column M.

Comment: Its weird. The criteria is ">"&DATE. So it will sum every date after the date. I tested it on my side and it worked.

Comment: Turns out the way my dates were stored weren't being read correctly - all fixed! Thanks Moacir!